# How to get X-Total-Count header with RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Don't know how to access the headers after the request. [Documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/pagination) examples without using `x-total-count`

```
const guitarApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'GUITARS',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllGuitars: builder.query<AllGuitarsResponse, number>({
      query: (limit = 1) => `${APIRoute.Guitars}_limit${limit}`,
    }),
  }),
});
```

I get them into the component like this

```
const { data: guitarData } = useGetAllGuitarsQuery(searchingParams);
```

Where can I access the response headers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `transformResponse` for this, it has the signature

```
  transformResponse?(
    baseQueryReturnValue: BaseQueryResult<BaseQuery>,
    meta: BaseQueryMeta<BaseQuery>,
    arg: QueryArg
  ): ResultType | Promise<ResultType>
```

and if you use `fetchBaseQuery`, `meta` will be

```
type FetchBaseQueryMeta = { request: Request; response?: Response }
```

So you can write your endpoint like:

```
const guitarApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'GUITARS',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllGuitars: builder.query<{ apiResponse: AllGuitarsResponse, totalCount: number}, number>({
      query: (limit = 1) => `${APIRoute.Guitars}_limit${limit}`,
      transformResponse(apiResponse, meta) {
        return { apiResponse, totalCount: Number(meta.response.headers.get('X-Total-Count')) }
      }
    }),
  }),
});
```